# From pandas dataframe to json file for Google Map API

Tags: python, json, pandas, google-maps-api-3

I have a pandas dataframe with two columns

```
      Lat       Long
0   53.0294   53.3256
1   13.6363   63.3632
2   22.5353   55.2201
...
```

Now I need json file to be perfect for use it for Google Map API.

To look like this:

```
[{"Lat": "45.496275", "Long": "19.700225"}
{"Lat": "43.9332040422", "Long": "21.3821478025"}
{"Lat": "43.7236250523", "Long": "20.6935022429"}]
```

I have tried with this:

```
out = coord_frame.to_json(orient='records')
```

Ang get this:

```
[{\"Lat\":44.8242557024,\"Long\":20.4048512901},{\"Lat\":44.8242557024,\"Long\":20.4048512901}]
```

I don't need those slashes and I'm not sure if I can use this in javascript code of Google Map API.

Comment: Use `df.to_dict('r')`?

Comment: @Zero Thank you. :)

Comment: The problem is with how you are saving your json. Can you add that code as well?

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
coord_frame.to_json('file.json', orient='records')
```

For writing `dict` to `file` use:

```
import json

out = coord_frame.to_dict(orient='records')

with open("file.json", 'w') as f:
    json.dump(out, f)
```

Comment: But when I save it to txt, I got those slashes.

Comment: I try some test and 2 solution was added. Unfortunately I cannot simulate your problem with backslashes, but I hope it working nice.